# PrettyTable add_row() Not Printing the Table Body

Tags: python, prettytable

To the best of ability I couldn't recognize why PrettyTable add_row method is not printing the table body in this my Python 3 code. It is a program to evaluate truth table and print the table out.

If I use print function, I am able to print the data out that is supposed to be printed out by the x.add_row() method of the PrettyTable.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# Write a general truth expresion for a statement ((P or Q) and (P or S or Q) and (P or R))

# import modules
import prettytable

P = [True, True, False, False]
Q = [True, False, True, False]
R = [True, False, True, False]
S = [False, True, False, True]


def print_result(P, Q, R, S, w, x, y, z):
    print(f"[+] Truth Table")

    x = prettytable.PrettyTable(["P","Q", "R", "S", "P or Q", "P or S or Q", "P or R", "(P or Q) and (P or S or Q) and (P or R)"])

    for a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h in zip(P, Q, R, S, w, x, y, z):
        x.add_row([a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h])
            
    print(f"{x}")



def p_or_q(P, Q):
    p_or_q_list = []

    for x, y in zip(P, Q):
        p_or_q_list.append(x or y)
    
    return p_or_q_list


def p_or_s_or_q(P, S, Q):
    p_or_s_or_q_list = []

    for x, y, z in zip(P, S, Q):
        p_or_s_or_q_list.append(x or y or z)

    return p_or_s_or_q_list     


def p_or_r(P, R):
    p_or_r_list = []

    for x, y in zip(P, R):
        p_or_r_list.append(x or y)

    return p_or_r_list  


def all_together(P, Q, R, S):
    all_together_list = []

    for a, b, c, d in zip(P, Q, R, S):
        all_together_list.append((a or b) and (a or d or b) and (a or c))

    return all_together_list    


w = p_or_q(P, Q)
x = p_or_s_or_q(P, S, Q)
y = p_or_r(P, R) 
z = all_together(P, Q, R, S)

print_result(P, Q, R, S, w, x, y, z)
```

This is what I am getting as output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fatoI.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but the `for` loop in `print_result` does not like the zip object being declared in the loop statement. It won't unpack when used there. If you store the `zip` object in a variable first and iterate the variable, it works fine.

```
def print_result(P, Q, R, S, w, x, y, z):

    print(f"[+] Truth Table")

    x = prettytable.PrettyTable()
    x.field_names = ["P","Q", "R", "S", "P or Q",
                     "P or S or Q", "P or R",
                     "(P or Q) and (P or S or Q) and (P or R)"]

    tuples = zip(P,Q,R,S,w,x,y,z)
    for a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h in tuples:
        x.add_row([a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h])

    print(f"{x}")
```